# Iterating through std:list<wstring>

Tags: c++, stdlist

This is my code:

```
for (std::list<std::wstring>::iterator itr  = kb->titles.begin(); itr != kb->titles.end() ; itr++)
    {
        _size += *itr.size();
    }
```

What I am trying to do is access every wstring contained in the list and call it's size() member function. However what's pointed by itr does not seem to be the iterated wstring element and I'm getting an error (error C2039: 'size' : is not a member of 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>')

In case you are wondering what kb is it's a pointer to a struct with `std::list<std::wstring> titles;` as one of it's members.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: With C++11 this becomes easy with the ranged-for loop: `for (auto title : titles) _size += title.size();`

Comment: @chris You probably want it to be `for( const auto& title : titles ) { /* .. */ }` in this case

Comment: @Prætorian, oops, you're right. I meant to put a const in there, and each one's a wstring so yeah :) Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Operator precedence is the issue here, try

```
_size += (*itr).size();
```

Or even better,

```
_size += itr->size();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the parenthesises:

```
_size += (*itr).size();
_size += itr->size();
```

Should both work.